# Microsoft Mappoint set pushpin name for .gpx export

Tags: gpx, pushpin, mappoint

I am trying to export a large set of pushpins together with their lat/lon data out of microsoft MapPoint. The normal export to excel doesn't include lat/lon info so I tried to circumvent this problem by doing a gpx export.
Sadly the name of the pushpins seems to be 'random' (using housenumbers), hence the usability of the generated gpx file is zero.

Is there a way to define the name of a pushpin based on a field upon importing a dataset?

Hepl is much apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with that last sentence, but the Name of each pushpin can be set with the Data import Wizard using the Name and Name2 import fields.

As for your larger problem, you are on a programming site, so I assume this is an option. You could write your own exporter. The longitude and latitude information are available through the Pushpin's Location field (properties: Longitude, Latitude).

Alternatively, Support PC sell Pushpin Tool which can export pushpin information to Excel complete with longitude,latitude info.